# Is there a way to end a windows task (not a process) with the command-line?

Tags: c, windows, process, terminal

In "Windows Task Manager" tool, under "Allpications" tab there is a function called "End Task". I want to accomplish this job through terminal. Is there any way to do it?

It is not close a process which can be done with command "taskkill". Because may be several "task" instances are pointing to one process. For example, open several emails, it's actually associated with one process named "OUTOOK.exe". While I just want to close one instance.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I created a tool to do it. I think there is no available commands to do it directly. Thanks you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roll your own.

To do so: Find the window, probably by title/caption using [`FindWindow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`EnumWindows()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then send it a [`WM_CLOSE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632617%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message using [`SendMessage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of a process to kill, for example notepad.exe, use the following command from a command prompt to end it:

```
taskkill /IM notepad.exe
```

To kill a single instance of a process, specify its process id (PID). For example, if the desired process has a PID of 827, use the following command to kill it:

```
taskkill /PID 827
```

Answer (score -1):

You must get the task PID with the command TASKLIST, then kill the task with TASKKILL /PID XXXX, with XXXX as the task PID

Comment: Commands "TASKLIST"&"TASKKILL" are used for processes. What I want is to close the running "applications" in windows. The exact feature in "Windows Task Manager" is "End Task" under "Applications" tab.

Comment: i found that you can use tasklist /fi "windowtitle eq YOUR WINDOW NAME" and get its PID, but windowtitle doesnt work correctly, so, my solution could be taken as right, try it     tasklist /fi "windowtitle eq filename - notepad"